# Appium xpath escaping apostrophes

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, appium, apostrophe

I have the code below in my appium script:

```
    public boolean isErrorDisplayedUnrecognisedLoginCredentials() {
        return appDriver.isElementExist(By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[@name='We don't recognize this user ID or password']"));
    }
```

The test is hanging since it treats the apostrophe in "don't" as a final apostrophe to close off the @name value.  I have tried escaping the apostrophe in "don't" by using \', \', '

However, none of these are working and the tests keep failing.  Anyone know how to get round this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't escape quotes in xpath, but you can escape quotes in Java. So try to use escaped double quotes for the xpath literal string delimiter, for example :

```
By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[@name=\"We don't recognize this user ID or password\"]")
```

Comment: You can escape quotes and apostrophes in XPath 2.0 by doubling them, but there is no way of doing it in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 1.0 (It should work with XPath 2.0):

```
By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[@name='We don&apos;t recognize this user ID or password']")
```

With XPath 2.0 we have two solutions:

1. By doubling the single apostrophe you will be able to escape the apostrophe:
   `By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[@name='We don''t recognize this user ID or password']")`

**Recommended solution:**

2. To define the Xpath, I would use the double quote (") instead of a apostrophe:
   `By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[@name="We don't recognize this user ID or password"]")`