# Using an apostrophe in an xpath expression

Tags: java, xpath, escaping

I have some html like this:

```html
<a>This is the Children's Miracle Network</a>
```

I as expected am getting an error when I do

```
 WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'This is the Children's Miracle Network)]"));
```

because the apostrophe in Children's is unquoting the text.  I tried using double ' (like '') and backslashing (\') but that did not work.  I am not sure what to do?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appium xpath escaping apostrophes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778287/appium-xpath-escaping-apostrophes)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),\"This is the Children's Miracle Network\")]"));
```

Comment: Do I have to double backslash?

Comment: Nothing worked.  I ended up splitting on ' and using contains(text(),'firstpart') and contains(text(),'secondpart')].  Actually I split on the ' and count the fields and make a contains(text()) for each field.  There could be more than   like "Children's parent's miracle network's main charity"