# How can I escape double quotes in a Xpath in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

For Example:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id="ext-gen1035"]/div/div[3]/i")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quote in xpath 1.0 in selenium for python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759318/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-xpath-1-0-in-selenium-for-python)

Comment: Also related : [Appium xpath escaping apostrophes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778287/appium-xpath-escaping-apostrophes/30778431#30778431)

Answer (score 13):

You can actually use *single quotes* too:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen1035']/div/div[3]/i")
```

Or escape double quotes with a backslash:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ext-gen1035\"]/div/div[3]/i")
```

Comment: Escaping with backslashes was apparently (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32759467/140707) only introduced in XPath 2.0, which still doesn't have wide adoption.